# Edit ArrayrList<Object> prints different result

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with objects `Order` where

```
public class Order{
    private String product;
    private String version;   
    ArrayList<String> availableVersions;    
    //etc..
}
```

and in the beginning the objects are like `Order o = new Order ("product1", "01");`. So I want to group all the objects with the same product name and combine all the different versions which may have. I have done:

```
//ArrayList<Order> labels contains data with o objects.

for(Order o:labels){
    System.out.println("1: product " + o.getProduct() + " has versions " + o.getVersion());
}

ArrayList<Order> temp = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> versions = new ArrayList<>();
String product;

for(Order o:labels){    
    product = o.getProduct(); //store the name of product to compare it with the list in the following loop.
    temp.clear();
    versions.clear();   

    for(Order o1:labels){
        if(product.equals(o1.getProduct())){ //collect all the object with the same product name in a temporary list.
            temp.add(o1); 
        }
    }

    for(Order lb:temp){ //iterate the list and get the version of each element
        versions.add(lb.getVersion());               
    }

    o.setAvailableVersions(versions); //add the list with all the versions in the current object.
    System.out.println("2: product " + o.getProduct() + " has versionss " + o.getAvailableVersions());
}

for(Order o:labels){
    System.out.println("3: product " + o.getProduct() + " has versionss " + o.getAvailableVersions());
}
```

And I get

```
1: product 25043625 has versionss 01
1: product 25043625 has versionss 02
2: product 25043625 has versionss [01, 02]
2: product 25043625 has versionss [01, 02]
3: product 25043625 has versionss [01]
3: product 25043625 has versionss [01]
```

Why???? I print the same object? why outputs `2:` and `3:` are different?

Comment: can you explain the -1 vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal if the results are different. Because your `versions` variable has the same reference everywhere.
Everytime you enter the loop, you are still modifying the same `versions` list as the one for the previous iteration, thus changing the previous values.
If you want to fix it, you need to initialise it inside the `for` loop like this

```
ArrayList<Order> temp = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> versions;
String product;

for(Order o:labels){
    product = o.getProduct(); //store the name of product to compare it with the list in the following loop.
    temp.clear();
    versions = new ArrayList<>();
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Hope it can help you

#### Optimization

You can optimize your code and change this part:

```
for(Order o1:labels){
    if(product.equals(o1.getProduct())){ //collect all the object with the same product name in a temporary list.
        temp.add(o1); 
    }
}

for(Order lb:temp){ //iterate the list and get the version of each element
    versions.add(lb.getVersion());               
}
```

To this

```
for(Order o1:labels){
    if(product.equals(o1.getProduct())){ //collect all the object with the same product name in a temporary list.
        versions.add(o1.getVersion());
    }
}
```

and then get rid of `temp` variable